# Will it hurt performance to make ListAdapter.getView() synchronized?

Tags: android, listview, thread-safety, android-listview, listadapter

In my code I've found that for performance reasons to prevent repeated and slow dependent object instantiations, it would be tremendously helpful to assume that the calls to `ArrayAdapter.getView()` are not executed concurrently by marking it `synchronized`.

Is there any reason to believe that Android issues multi-threaded calls to getView and that applying the `synchronized` keyword will hurt performance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getView()` will only be called on the main application thread, unless for some bizarre reason you call it yourself on a background thread. Hence, synchronization is unnecessary and will add overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  Is there somewhere in the Android API that mentions that the system won't spawn multiple threads now or in future revisions to take advantage of multi-core processors?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Threads -- "This thread is very important because it is in charge of dispatching events to the appropriate user interface widgets, including drawing events. It is also the thread in which your application interacts with components from the Android UI toolkit (components from the android.widget and android.view packages)." Multiple cores will be for use with background threads you spawn; the UI will remain single-threaded for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Thanks very much for the info!  If you don't mind my asking, what is the source of your information about the UI remaining single threaded in future releases?

Comment: I've been doing Android development since early 2008 and know that the vast majority of applications will crash and burn if they change the single-threaded UI rule. Also, bear in mind that while the tech media loves to focus on bigger/faster/better, Android still needs to support low-end devices for many markets. The single-threaded UI model is there in large part to support low-end devices.

Comment: OK, well add my application to the list of ones that will crash and burn then, if your prediction ends up being wrong :)